# How to push object data in elasticksearch array field

Tags: python, elasticsearch

I want to push object data type inside an array field and i have error, I thing is the mapping

I Use Python to work with ElastickSearch

## Create the mappings for the customer

```
def create_customer_index():
    ''' Start creating customers index manually '''

    mapping = {
        "mappings": {
            "customer": {
                "properties": {
                    "created": {
                        "type": "long"
                    },
                    "updated": {
                        "type": "long"
                    },
                    "shopping_cart": {
                        "type": "text",
                        "fields": {
                            "keyword": {
                                "type": "keyword",
                                "ignore_above": 256
                            }
                        }
                    },

                }
            }
        }
    }

    es.indices.create(index='customers', body=mapping)
#end
```

### With this method I add the product the user select and the quantity inside the array

```
def add_item_in_shopping_cart(uid, product_id, quantity=1):
    ''' Add new item in customer shopping cart '''

    print('Start adding a new item in shopping cart')

    # print('UID => ', uid)
    print('Product id to add is: => ', product_id)

    # 1st check if the user has this product on favorites,
    # 2nd if the user doesn't have this remove it from the list

    customer_shoping_cart = get_customer_shopping_cart(uid)
    print('CUSTUMER SHOPING CART => ', customer_shoping_cart)

    x = False

    for item in customer_shoping_cart:
        if item == product_id:
            x = True
    if x:
        print('Item already exist in shopping_cart')
        return 'item_already_exist_in_shopping_cart', 500
    else:
        print('Item dont exist in shopping_cart, i gona added')
        timestamp = int(round(time.time() * 1000))

        schema = {
            "product_id": product_id,
            "quantity" : 10
        }
        doc = {
            "script" : {
                "inline":"ctx._source.shopping_cart.add(params.data)",
                "params":{
                    "data":{
                        "product_id": product_id,
                        "quantity" : quantity
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        try:
            es.update(index="customers", doc_type='customer', id=uid, body=doc)
            es.indices.refresh(index="customers")
            return jsonify({'message': 'item_added_in_shopping_cart'}), 200

        except Exception as e:
            print('ERROR => ', e)
            return 'we have error', 500
#end
```

### And I have this error

> ERROR =>  TransportError(400, 'mapper_parsing_exception', 'failed to parse [shopping_cart]')

Answer (score 0):

From the mapping you posted it looks like ElasticSearch expects documents like this:

```
{
  "created": 1510094303,
  "updated": 1510094303,
  "shopping_cart": "I am in a shopping cart"
}
```

Or like this:

```
{
  "created": 1510094303,
  "updated": 1510094303,
  "shopping_cart": [
    "I am in a shopping cart",
    "me too!"
  ]
}
```

And you are trying to treat `"shopping_cart"` is an array of objects, which it is not (it is an array of strings). ElasticSearch does not allow to put objects that do not fit the mapping into the index.

What you should try first is to change your mapping to something like this:

```
mapping = {
    "mappings": {
        "customer": {
            "properties": {
                "created": {
                    "type": "long"
                },
                "updated": {
                    "type": "long"
                },
                "shopping_cart": {
                    "properties": {
                        "product_id": {
                            "type": "keyword"
                        },
                        "quantity": {
                            "type": "integer"
                        }
                    }
                },

            }
        }
    }
}
```

Moreover, consider also changing the document entirely on the client side, i.e. in your script, and putting the new version document in the index (replacing the previous one), since it will probably be easier in the implementation logic (for instance, no need for ElasticSearch-side scripts to update the document).

Hope that helps.